# Android SQLite AlarmManager

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent, alarmmanager

I have some dates with the time stored in a database table. Now, at any date and time corresponding, I want to display a notification. I created this code but the notification is not created.

```
private void setAlarmFromDatabase(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String sql = "SELECT _id, riserva_3 FROM riserva";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        int count = c.getCount();
        String[] data_ora = new String[count];
        for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
            c.moveToNext();     
            data_ora[i] = c.getString(0);

        }
        c.close();
    db.close();

    AlarmManager[] alarmManager=new AlarmManager[24];
    for(int ii=0;ii<data_ora.length;ii++)
    {
       alarmManager[ii] = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);                

       Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Notifica.class);

      PendingIntent displayIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),ii,i,0);
      alarmManager[ii].set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,Long.parseLong(data_ora[ii]), displayIntent);
    }
    this.finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.left_out);
    }
```

The BroadcastReceiver

```
public class Notifica extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
    // Vibrate the mobile phone
    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vibrator.vibrate(1000);
    showNotification(context);
}
private void showNotification(Context context) {
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            new Intent(context, Login.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.testo_notifica));
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

}  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to find out form the code you've pasted. However I'd encourage you to check the following things :

1. What are the values of `data_ora[ii]` you are getting. Put a log after setting the alarm and check in logcat.
2. Have you registered your broadcast receiver, Notifica ?
3. Have you added vibrate permission to your app by adding this line in your manifest ?     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"></uses-permission>`

Comment: The variable `data_ora[ii]` is in this format `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm`. I declared the broadcast receiver. Now the notification is displayed immediately, and not at the time established. Maybe there is some error in the code?

Comment: I also added the permission, but same result.

Comment: parsing the long in the format yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm will result in number format exception. Example : Long.parseLong("2013-01-01 12:00"); gives number format exception.